# Angular - $scope can't access $http response in a service

Tags: angularjs, http, service, request

I have a service that I want to get data via `$http` (the reason for a service is because I need to make this call multiple times in my app)

The service is working great, this is the code:

```
factory('websiteService', function($rootScope, $http) {

    this.getWebsites = function(){
        http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: './data/websites.json'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }
    $rootScope.websiteService = this;
    return this;
});
```

Then, I'm using it in several controllers like so:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, websiteService) {
    $scope.websites = websiteService.getWebsites(); // not working
});
```

Though, as you guess this doesn't work. It seems that `websites` is defined before the `$http` request is ending, but I could be wrong.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Read the documentation for how to create services with a factory: you shouldn't use `this`, and you shouldn't modify the root scope). Then read http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/ to understand the trap about promises that you fell into, and how to fix it.

Comment: thanks will look into that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how the service should be defined:

```
myModule.factory('websiteService', function($http) {

    function getWebsites() {
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: './data/websites.json'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }

    return {
        getWebsites: getWebsites
    };
});
```

And here's how it should be used:

```
myModule.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, websiteService) {
    websiteService.getWebsites().then(function(webSites) {
        $scope.webSites = webSites;
    });
});
```

I suggest you read [Traps, anti-patterns and tips about AngularJS promises](http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/) to understand the mistakes you made about promises.

Comment: I learned so much from one answer, such a great article. thank you so much. FYI - little typo in line 3 `function getWebsites() {`

Comment: Fixed the typo. Thanks.

Comment: I want to improve my code so I save the http response to the user's local storage, but once its created I get an error when I use getWebsites().then() (`then() is not a function`) Can you to look at this gist? https://gist.github.com/Codeia/0711bbdc5eb555af19b136f040f3dcf5

Comment: The service either returns a promise, or an immediate result. You can't transform a promise into an immediate result. But you can transform an immediate result into a promise: `return $q.when(localStorageService.get('websites'));`

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir.